# Flutter integration_test, screenshot function is unable to capture the entire screen. How do i make it screenshot the entire view

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

The screenshot image that i received, does not include the status bar portion of the app. As you can see below(the first image), the very upper part of the app is being cut off.

[image: 1st Image]

The 2nd image is the kind of image i am expecting but failed to obtained.

[image: 2nd Image]

// My screenshot_test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';
import 'package:end_point/main.dart' as app;

void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final binding = IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  group('App test', () {
    testWidgets("test infinite pagination", (tester) async {
        
      app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await binding.convertFlutterSurfaceToImage();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await binding.takeScreenshot('screenshot-home');
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    });
  });
}
```

// my integration_test.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver_extended.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await integrationDriver(
    onScreenshot: (String screenshotName, List<int> screenshotBytes) async {
      final File image = File('ss/$screenshotName.png');
      image.writeAsBytesSync(screenshotBytes);
      // Return false if the screenshot is invalid.
      return true;
    },
  );
}
```

I run the code using

"flutter drive 
--driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart 
--target=integration_test/screenshot_test.dart 
-d iPhone SE"

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust screen resolution:

```
flutter drive \
  --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
  --target=integration_test/screenshot_test.dart \
  --size=750x1334 \
  -d iPhone SE
```

Comment: I am getting this "Could not find an option named "size"." error, tried searching online but was unable to find similar problem.

In additional i have tried setting the window size with these code:


`final width = 750;`
`final height = 1334;`
`final dpi = tester.binding.window.devicePixelRatio;`
`tester.binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = Size(width * dpi, height * dpi);`

But it doesn't really do anything too.

Comment: I found this website https://keyholesoftware.com/2023/02/13/automating-flutter-deployments-part-2-screenshots/#respond post, the person was facing the same problem and she mentioned that the reason why this is happening because "integration_test package takes screenshots within the context of the Flutter application; it doesn’t know about OS features like status bars".

I am trying out her solution and if i managed to get it working, i will post it here.